# Appended checkbox divs causing color highlight problems

Tags: jquery, html, css, append

My code starts by appending country checkboxes from 2 divs, to a 3rd div.  This 3rd (or 'holding' div.), then appends its contents back and forth between a number of other divs., as and when required.  Somehow this has managed to mess up the highlighting color of the checkboxes.  The 'Year' checkboxes should be white on blue background, while the 'Country' checkboxes should be red on yellow background.  I've been hours trying to work out why the colors don't obey their CSS code.  Can anyone help?  http://jsfiddle.net/o1Ljyf31/

```js
 $('#CountryList1 label, #CountryList2 label').appendTo($('.CountryRHWrapperClass'))
    $('.CountryRHWrapperClass').appendTo($('.CountryListBoxClass_ws'))
    $('.CountryListBoxClass_ws').show()


    jQuery.fn.multiselect= function() {
    $(this).each(function() {
        var checkboxes = $(this).find("input:checkbox");
        checkboxes.each(function() {
            var checkbox = $(this);

            // Highlight checkboxes that the user selects
            checkbox.change(function() {
                if (checkbox.prop("checked"))
                    checkbox.parent().addClass("CountryListBoxClass_ws-on YearListBoxClass_ws-on");
                else
                    checkbox.parent().removeClass("CountryListBoxClass_ws-on YearListBoxClass_ws-on");
  });
  });
});
};
$(".CountryListBoxClass_ws, .YearListBoxClass_ws").multiselect();
```

```css
#ContainerForYearListBoxID_ws {
  height: 40px;
  border: solid 1px red;
}
.CountryListBoxClass_ws label {
  display:block;
  background: lightgrey;
  height: 40px;
}
.YearListBoxClass_ws-on {
  color:white;
  background-color:blue;
}
.CountryListBoxClass_ws-on {
  color: red;
  background-color:yellow;
} 
.myEuropeCountries {
  display: none;
  float:left;  
}
.mySAMCountries {
  display: none;
  float:left;  
}
.myAfricaMECountries {
  display: none;
  float:left;  
}
.myEastAsiaCountries {
  display: none;
  float:left;  
}
```

```html
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js

    <div id="ContainerForYearListBoxID_ws">
    <div id="YearListBoxID_ws" class="YearListBoxClass_ws">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="2015" />2015</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="2014" />2014</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="2013" />2013</label>
    </div>
    </div>
    <br>

    <!-- Move countries from storage to listbox -->
    <div id="CountryListBoxID_ws" class="CountryListBoxClass_ws"></div>

    <!-- Country storage -->
    <div class="CountryRHWrapperClass"></div>

    <div id="CountryList1">
    <label class="myEuropeCountries"><input type="checkbox" value="Austria"  />Austria</label>
    <label class="mySAMCountries"><input type="checkbox" value="Brazil" />Brazil</label>
    </div>

    <div id="CountryList2">
    <label class="myAfricaMECountries"><input type="checkbox" value="Algeria" />Algeria</label>
    <label class="myEastAsiaCountries"><input type="checkbox" value="Japan" />Japan</label>
    </div>
```

Comment: Js line 15 : `checkbox.parent().addClass("CountryListBoxClass_ws-on YearListBoxClass_ws-on");`
Why you add both css class ? On my code inspector i can see .CountryListBoxClass_ws-on override .YearListBoxClass_ws-on css

Comment: Thanks, but not sure I understand.  Each CSS class refers to a different div and listbox.  I need the highlighting to apply to both.  I'm afraid I don't know what you mean by 'override'.

Comment: Look your html with Chrome dev-tools (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/) , you apply two class (CountryListBoxClass_ws-on and YearListBoxClass_ws-on) at same element, so only last class apply CSS

Comment: OK, I understand now.  Thanks for your advice.